# Arrow Functions and This

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm trying out ES6 and want to include a property inside my function like so

```
var person = {
  name: "jason",

  shout: () => console.log("my name is ", this.name)
}

person.shout() // Should print out my name is jason
```

However, when I run this code console only logs `my name is`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.es6fiddle.net/

Comment: `this` in this case is Window.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Short answer: `this` points at the nearest bound `this` - in the code provided `this` is found in the enclosing scope.

Longer answer: Arrow functions
[do not have `this`, `arguments` or other special names bound *at all*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160625172303/http://blog.getify.com/arrow-this/) - when the object is being created the name `this` is found in the enclosing scope, not the `person` object.  You can see this more clearly by moving the declaration:

```
var person = {
  name: "Jason"
};
person.shout = () => console.log("Hi, my name is", this);
```

And even more clear when translated into a vague approximation of the arrow syntax in ES5:

```
var person = {
  name: "Jason"
};
var shout = function() {
  console.log("Hi, my name is", this.name);
}.bind(this);
person.shout = shout;
```

In both cases, `this` (for the shout function) points to the same scope as `person` is defined in, not the new scope that the function is attached to when it is added to the `person` object.

You *cannot* make arrow functions work that way, but, as @kamituel points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798419/135978), you *can* take advantage of the shorter method declaration pattern in ES6 to get similar space savings:

```
var person = {
  name: "Jason",
  // ES6 "method" declaration - leave off the ":" and the "function"
  shout() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is", this.name);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 33):

Agreed with @Sean Vieira - in this case `this` is bound to the global object (or, as pointed out in the comment, more generally to an enclosing scope).

If you want to have a shorter syntax, there is another option - enhanced object literals support short syntax for property functions. `this` will be bound as you expect there. See `shout3()`:

```
window.name = "global";

var person = {
    name: "jason",

    shout: function () {
        console.log("my name is ", this.name);
    },
    shout2: () => {
        console.log("my name is ", this.name);
    },
    // Shorter syntax
    shout3() {
        console.log("my name is ", this.name);
    }
};

person.shout();  // "jason"
person.shout2(); // "global"
person.shout3(); // "jason"
```

Comment: Upvoted, but note `this` won't necessarily be the global object.

Comment: @Oriol true, noted - I assumed this is top level code. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is excellent, concise, and clear but i will elaborate a little on what Sean Vieira said:

> Arrow functions do not have
>   this arguments or other special names bound at all.

Because the arrow function doesn't have a "this", it uses the parent's "this".  "this" always points to the parent, and the parent of the person object is Window (if you're in a browser).

To prove it run this in your console:

```
var person = {
    name: "Jason",
    anotherKey: this
}
console.log(person.anotherKey)
```

You'll get the Window object.

I find this to be a really helpful way to think about it.  It isn't quite the full story, as what the "this" of an object literal is is another discussion.

Comment: brilliant - i try to understand  why its happen so much time!!!!

Comment: Very clearly explained. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here the value of this inside of the function is determined by where the arrow function is defined not where it is used.

So `this` refers to global/window object if not wrapped in other namespace

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

> An arrow function expression [...] lexically binds the this value.
>
> Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context.

Therefore, the value of `this` in that function will be the value of `this` where you create the object literal. Probably, that will be `window` in non-strict mode and `undefined` in strict mode.

To fix it, you should use a normal function:

```
var person = {
  name: "jason",
  shout: function(){ console.log("my name is ", this.name) }
}
person.shout();
```