# Why does the es6 version of my function say "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Tags: function, ecmascript-6

This version of my es6 function doesn't work:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = () => {
  let results = [];

  this.forEach((subArray) => {
    subArray.forEach((item) => {
      results.push(item);
    });
  });

  return results;
};
```

When I use it like this:

```
var stocks = exchanges.concatAll();
```

The console says: `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

However this es5 version works just fine:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  let results = [];

  this.forEach((subArray) => {
    subArray.forEach((item) => {
      results.push(item);
    });
  });

  return results;
};
```

Why is this? What exactly is happening with `this` inside the es6 version? I would like to understand.

Comment: You cannot use arrow functions as methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow Functions and This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been mentioned, but this isn't a good use-case for arrow functions due to the fact that they bind the value of `this`. Another way you can do this with ES6 is to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

For your example:

```
Object.assign(Array.prototype, {
  concatAll() {
    let results = [];

    this.forEach(subArr => {
      subArr.forEach(item => {
        results.push(item);
      });
    });

    return results;
  }
});
```

And then you could just use the code like this:

```
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

console.log(arr.concatAll()); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

You can also add on multiple methods like this:

```
Object.assign(Array.prototype, {
  sum() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  },

  max() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => (a > b) ? a : b);
  },

  min() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => (a < b) ? a : b);
  }
});

let arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.sum()); // -> 6
console.log(arr.max()); // -> 3
console.log(arr.min()); // -> 1
```

Comment: Here can be shorter implementation of `concatAll`: `return this.reduce((res, subArr) => [...res, ...subArr], [])`

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function's scope of `this` is it's parent scope. So in this case `this` is undefined. So in this case you would still need a function.

Check the start of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target)**. Arrow functions are always anonymous.

ES6 can still simplify your code though by using `for of`:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function(){
  let results = []
  for(let subArray of this)
    for(let item of subArray)
      results.push(item)
  return results
}
```

Comment: How could your code work? You said yourself that `this` is not going to be referring to the array.

Comment: @saadq Oops I forgot to use function too, fixed :)