# ES6, arrow function, context of "this"

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I thought that arrow function is "just" a shortcut for antonymous functions, so I've been using it quite a lot. However, recently I came across an example that arrow function caused some issues. Here's a sample code:

```
function refreshTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: root + `/posts?userId=${userId}`,
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {

    for (var item of data) {
      $('table.list tbody').append(`
            <tr>
              <td>${item.id}</td>
              <td>${item.title}</td>
              <td>${item.date}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="" data-id="${item.id}" class="getDetails">View</a> | 
                <a href="" data-id="${item.id}" class="getDetails">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          `);
    }

    $('.getDetails').click((e) => {
    // $(this) is actually the ajax call, I can't access the "data" part
    });

  });
}
```

However, this works:

```
    function refreshTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: root + `/posts?userId=${userId}`,
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {

    for (var item of data) {
      $('table.list tbody').append(`
            <tr>
              <td>${item.id}</td>
              <td>${item.title}</td>
              <td>${item.date}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="" data-id="${item.id}" class="getDetails">View</a> | 
                <a href="" data-id="${item.id}" class="getDetails">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          `);
    }

    $('.getDetails').click(function(e) {
    // $(this) is the HTML element, so I can access "data"
    });

  });
}
```

Obviously, there is some logic to arrow functions, it creates a different scope for `this`. So, what's going on? Could I achieve the same thing with an arrow function (to access HTML) or is that not possible in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow Functions and This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: Someone has a bad day? Downvoting good answers without leaving a comment. If these are strategical downvotes...well if it means so much to you :)

Answer (score 1):

> Could I achieve the same thing with an arrow function (to access HTML) or is that not possible in this case?

You can use an arrow function, but you can't use `this`. You can refer to the element the handler is bound to via the event object: [`e.currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

> This property will typically be equal to the `this` of the function.

---

> So, what's going on?

See:

- [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)
- [Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are experiencing exactly what an arrow function does. It takes the `this` from the lexical or parent scope. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

> Second, their this is picked up from surroundings (lexical). Therefore, you don’t need bind() or that = this, anymore.

Yes, you can make it work, but you need to put the HTML Element outside of the click function. Then you can use `this` inside the function and not having the problem of using his own `this`.

Answer (score 0):

[An arrow function does not create its own this context; rather, it captures the this value of the enclosing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

In the specific case you are describing, you can just use `$(e.target).data('id')` to retrieve the data.