# Why doesn't this arrow function work in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Below piece of code does not work in IE 11, it throws a syntax error in the console

```
g.selectAll(".mainBars")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", d => (d.part == "primary" ? -40 : 40))
    .attr("y", d => +6)
    .text(d => d.key)
    .attr("text-anchor", d => (d.part == "primary" ? "end" : "start"));
```

Using `d3.js` bipartite chart for visualization

This code causing the issue in above statement `d=>(d.part=="primary"? -40: 40)`

Comment: IE11 does not support the arrow notation for anonymous functions. Rewrite it as `function (d) { return d.part == "primary" ? -40 : 40; }`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Not all arrow functions are anonymous. This one isn't, for instance: `var f = () => "foo";`

Comment: See [here for which browsers support this syntax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

Comment: ^^ ... or [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: As a bonus, it doesn't even support the `=>` comparison operator (as in `if (a=>0)`). (if anyone was googling that and landed here, like me)

Comment: @David Balažic Your code is wrong. `if (a=>0)` is always true. This is because what you did was create a function, not a comparison and functions are truthy. `if (a<=0)` would be the correct way to write that.

Comment: @user3654410 it works as expected in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: `a=>0` is a function that always returns 0. Write it in your console now `x = a=>0` and inspect x. Or try `(a=>0)()`. All comparison operators are supported in all browsers.

Comment: `=>` is not a comparison function. It's an arrow function if the browser supports it, otherwise it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You're using arrow functions. IE11 doesn't support them. Use `function` functions instead.

Here's [Babel's](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&code=g.selectAll(%22.mainBars%22).append(%22text%22).attr(%22x%22%2Cd%3D%3E(d.part%3D%3D%22primary%22%3F%20-40%3A%2040)).attr(%22y%22%2Cd%3D%3E%2B6).text(d%3D%3Ed.key).attr(%22text-anchor%22%2Cd%3D%3E(d.part%3D%3D%22primary%22%3F%20%22end%22%3A%20%22start%22))%3B) translation of that to ES5:

```
g.selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("x", function (d) {
  return d.part == "primary" ? -40 : 40;
}).attr("y", function (d) {
  return +6;
}).text(function (d) {
  return d.key;
}).attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
  return d.part == "primary" ? "end" : "start";
});
```

Since none of the code uses `this`, you don't have to worry about preserving arrow function `this` behavior (since traditional functions get their `this` by how they're called, but arrow functions [*close over* `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)). But if the code did use `this` and you wanted it to behave like an arrow function would, you'd want to use [the usual techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for that.

Comment: don't forget about `this`: `var f = (a) => {a.some1(); this.some2();};` to `var f = function(a) {a.some1(); this.some2();}.bind(this);`

Comment: To clarify @user1742529's comment, the arrow function automatically binds `this` where `function(){...}` does not.  In systems like VueJS, it will cause issues.  `function(){...}.bind(this)` is more similar to arrow functions.

Comment: @user1742529 & Nathan - None of the code in the question uses `this`, hence no need to do anything to preserve it. But I've added a paragraph.

Answer (score 22):

Avoid use of arrow functions if you need to support IE 11 as [it is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

Change those to regular functions and your code should work as you expect

```
g.selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("x",function(d) { 
  return d.part=="primary"? -40: 40;
}).attr("y",function(d){
  return +6;
}).text(function(d) { 
  return d.key;
}).attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
  return d.part=="primary"? "end": "start";
});
```

Answer (score 21):

In general, before arrow functions were arrow functions, they were regular JS `function`s. So with IE11 we just have to take a step back in time

```
var fruits=["apple","banana","orange"];

var modernResult=fruits.find(e => e.includes("nana"));
console.log(modernResult);

var IEresult=fruits.find(function(e){return e.includes("nana")});
console.log(IEresult);
```

Comment: This code doesn't resemble the code in the question at all (and "don't use arrow functions" says nothing that every other answer hasn't already said)

Comment: True, however this question is the first search result for "arrow function not working in IE" and I gave a simple and less specific (more general) explanation. But I understand it's against the rules, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support the arrow notation as of now but there is a handy and fast way for transpiling your `ES6` codes to `ES5.1` for working in `IE`. visit the [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) website then paste your codes in the left box and copy the right box code that is transpiled to the earlier version of `JavaScript`.

For example, your code is transpiled to:

```
"use strict";

g.selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("x", function (d) {
   return d.part == "primary" ? -40 : 40;
}).attr("y", function (d) {
   return +6;
}).text(function (d) {
   return d.key;
}).attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
   return d.part == "primary" ? "end" : "start";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer(IE) doesn't support the ES6 functions at all, but you could install [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/). But you can also write the vanillaJS functions instead.

For example:

`const hasBrownEyes = eye.color === "brown" ? true : false`

Or just vanilla.js:

```
var hasBrownEyes = false; // default answer, it will be overwritten if it has a brown eye

if (eye.color === "brown") {
    return true;
}
```