# systam error at replace line in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, i am trying to call function while login time, but i am getting error in browser console in IE11.

```
function myLogin(){
    alert("login alert89");
    var str =document.getElementById("j_password").value;       
    var enc = window.btoa(str);

var chars = {'a':'b','b':'c','c':'a'};
var new1;
new1 = enc.replace(/[abc]/g, m => chars[m]);
    document.getElementById("j_password").value=new1;

}
```

I am getting `systam error` at `new1 = enc.replace(/[abc]/g, m => chars[m])` line. But is working in chrome. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Change `m => chars[m]` to `function(m) { return chars[m]; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Arrow function" not working in IE, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why)

Comment: Do you mean syntax error?