# How can I change these arrow functions to regular functions to support IE?

Tags: javascript

I have only just discovered from S.O that arrow functions are not available in IE :(

["Arrow function" not working in IE, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why)

I am using [Barba](http://barbajs.org/).js to transition between web pages.

```
var transEffect = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function () {
            this.newContainerLoading.then(val => this.fadeInNewContent($(this.newContainer)));
        },
        fadeInNewContent: function (nc) {

            . . . 
            // fade outy stuff


            $(this.oldContainer).delay(800).fadeOut(400).promise().done(() => {
                nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
                nc.fadeIn(800, function () {
                    $('#loader').removeClass('loading');
                    _this.done();

                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function () {
        return transEffect;
    };
    Barba.Pjax.start();
```

How can I convert these arrow functions to use `functions` instead?

[image: IE dev tools displaying error on arrow function]

I could wrap this script inside of an `if` Navigator userAgent but this is not ideal.

Comment: honestly, you should use Webpack to do this for you.

Comment: Webpack can do this for you? Woah!!

Comment: @Speir: ? webpack doesn't transform code. Maybe you mean https://babeljs.io/ .

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function expression and `.bind(this)` to set the value of `this` *inside* the function to the same value as outside:

```
function(val) { this.fadeInNewContent($(this.newContainer)); }.bind(this)
```

The general transformation rules for arrow functions using `this` would be:

```
// From
(arg1, arg2, ...) => expression
(arg1, arg2, ...) => { statement1; statement2; ...}

// TO
function (arg1, arg2, ...) { return expression; }.bind(this);
function (arg1, arg2, ...) { statement1; statement2; ... }.bind(this);
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Thanks, Felix. That error has disappeared. Can you help with the other, just below? `$(this.oldContainer).delay(800).fadeOut(400).promise().done(() => `

Comment: Basically the same. Except that function doesn't use `this`, so no reason to use `.bind(this)`.

Comment: Can't thank you enough :-)