# why i am getting syntax error in internet explorer 11 but in chrome it's perfectly working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

i have one java script method which is perfectly working in chrome but in internet explorer 11 i ma getting syntax error in this method

```
 onMenuOpen: function (e) {
            var isIe = detectIE();
            if (isIe === false){
                var itemKeys = [e.target.dataset.id];
                var menu = e.sender;
                menu.setOptions({
                    dataSource: itemKeys.map((itemKey) => {
                        return {
                            text: "<div data-item-key='" + itemKey + "'>ADD</div>",
                            cssClass: "context-menu-item",
                            encoded: false
                        };
                    })
                });
            }
        },
```

i am getting error in this line **"  dataSource: itemKeys.map((itemKey) => "** could any one pleasehelp for this problem

Comment: If you get an error, post the exact message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11

Comment: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error common.js (773,57)

Comment: @ThumChoonTat thanx