# I get a syntax error when using this line of code in ie11

Tags: angularjs, lodash, internet-explorer-11

I get a syntax error when using this line of code in IE11.

```
let themes = _.filter(data, (el) => {
    if (OrganizationId == 21) {
        return el.Code == 'skin-3';
    } else {
        return el.Code != 'skin-3';
    }
});
```

Comment: See this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't this arrow function work in IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 0):

You're using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) which is not supported by IE and [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility) which is partial supported by IE.

I suggest that you transpile the code to ES5 syntax using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). You can convert the code to below to make it work in IE 11:

```
var themes = _.filter(data, function (el) {
  if (OrganizationId == 21) {
    return el.Code == 'skin-3';
  } else {
    return el.Code != 'skin-3';
  }
});
```

Comment: see [How to create IE11 Bundles with Webpack 5 and Babel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035451/how-to-create-ie11-bundles-with-webpack-5-and-babel-7)