# Internet Explorer not executing event listener nor logging to console inside of useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following useEffect hook including an event listener which is not working on IE 11.

```
export function BigList({list, style}) {

    const ref = useRef({})

    useEffect(function() {
        const bg = document.querySelector('.background'),
            panel = ref.current

        console.log('start function')

        let colored = false

        function onScroll() {

            const {top, height} = panel.getBoundingClientRect()

            console.log('scrolling', top)

            if (top - height * 0.6 <= 0 && top + height * 0.4 >= 0 && !colored) {
                bg.classList.add("bg-colored")
                bg.classList.add("bg-animate")
                colored = true
            } else if ((top - height * 0.6 > 0 || top + height * 0.4 < 0) && colored) {
                bg.classList.remove("bg-colored")
                setTimeout(function() {
                    bg.classList.remove("bg-animate")
                }, 500)
                colored = false
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
        return function() {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="big-list panel z" id="why" style={style} ref={ref}>
            ....
        </div>
    )
}
```

It's working fine on any browser, but not for IE. - It's not even logging `start` - how so? Any ideas?

Comment: Is this transpiled into something that IE understands? Otherwise there should be a syntax error in the console

Comment: No version of IE understands arrow functions, see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why). If you **are** transpiling so you're not giving IE an arrow function, please add that information along with what the transpiled code looks like to the question and ping me, and I can reopen it. (You haven't shown any JSX, but most React projects transpile at least to process JSX expressions, so the question is really whether your project is set up to output ES5 or something more modern.)

Comment: Removing all arrow functions doesn't make it any better. IE doesn't understand `const {top, height}` which would also cause a syntax error. Please add a [mcve] with the **actual script** that doesn't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It wasn't about the arrow function, but about another library I imported inside of another component, removing the import for IE worked - somehow this error stopped other components from working

Comment: @Tim - I'm glad you figured it out!