# This context in arrow function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have a react component which looks like this.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { Accordion, Panel, PanelGroup, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';


const FormCell = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <a className="pdf-name" onClick={this.doSomething}>{data.item.extension.nameCodeDes}</a>
  </div>
);

class Docs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doSomething= this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }

  doSomething() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("here we are");
    })
  }

  // ...
}

Docs.defaultProps = {
  tableData: null,
  cols: null,
  metaData: {
    documentsColumnMetaData: [
      {
        displayName: 'Policy/Account',
        columnComponent: {
          component: FormCell,
          actions: [],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default Docs;
```

The this.doSomething is transpiled to undefined.doSomething in dev tools. I get an error Cannot read property 'downloadDocument' of undefined. Can someone please let me know what I'm missing here? 
P.S FormCell does more that what is posted. I reduced the code for simplicity

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... where are you seeing `undefined.doSomething`? Are you talking about your `FormCell` component, where you're referencing `this.doSomething`? If so, then that makes sense, since it looks like you're trying to reference a class instance property using `this` from outside the context of that class instance.

Comment: console says "Cannot read property 'downloadDocument' of undefined"

Comment: If the error message is referring to a property that's not in the source you posted, that's a pretty good indication that you've removed too much from your source.

Comment: I meant to  
console says "Cannot read property 'doSomething' of undefined"

Comment: That makes no sense. What value do you expect `this` to refer to inside `FormCell`?

Comment: You should definitely have a look at [Arrow Functions and This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28798330/218196).

Comment: This whole thing just looks like your doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're doing it wrong but I'll still answer your question directly. The issue here is that you are defining `FormCell` outside of `Docs` but you expect `this` to be an instance of `Docs`. What you can do is

change it to:

```
const FormCell = ({ data, doSomething }) => (
    <div>
        <a className="pdf-name" onClick={doSomething}>{data.item.extension.nameCodeDes}</a>
    </div>
);
```

And then I assume that you omitted some code inside the `Docs` component that looks like this

```
const ColumnComponent = this.props.metaData.documentsColumnMetaData[ 0 ].columnComponent.component;
return <ColumnComponent data={ someData } doSomething={ this.doSomething } />;
```

Notice how I added the `doSomething={ this.doSomething }`. That will allow you to pass the `doSomething` method to the `FormCell` component as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not have a `this`, instead `this` falls through to the upper scope. I'm not sure why it's undefined in this specific case, but this isn't territory you want to be in normally. Looking at this code I would guess `this` would be the global object, but maybe a top level arrow function referencing `this` is supposed to behave this way.

If you want to bind the function, define it with the `function` keyword instead.

```
function FormCell({ data }) {
    return <div>
        <a className="pdf-name" onClick={this.doSomething}>{data.item.extension.nameCodeDes}</a>
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: And even in this case, `doSomething` is on `Docs`, not `FormCell`.

Comment: I have tried this out Andy.  If you see the default props, FormCell has to be a value,not a function.

Comment: The `this` inside the arrow function refers to the `this` of the module. `this` inside a module evaluates to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment I made above...

You've got two different components in your code example: `FormCell` and `Docs`. There appears to be no relationship between them, *except that* you're referring to an undefined `this.doSomething` function in the `FormCell` component, which happens to have the same name as a `doSomething` function declared as a method on the `Docs` component. This leads me to think that they are supposed to be the same function.

So, working from that assumption...

The `this.doSomething` function referred to in `FormCell` should refer to a `FormCell.doSomething` function. After all, `this.doSomething` is being called *from within* the function that's rendering a `FormCell` component - it should refer to `FormCell` then. But you haven't defined a `doSomething` function on the `FormCell` component, so there's nothing for it to refer to (and you should be getting a "doSomething is not a function" or "doSomething is undefined" error).

If it is your intention to have the `this.doSomething` in the `FormCell` refer to the `doSomething` function on an instance of the `Docs` component, then you'll need to pass that function in to the `FormCell` component as a prop.

Comment: *"that's rendering a `FormCell` component - it should refer to `FormCell` then"* `this` never refers to the function itself, so that conclusion doesn't make sense to me, but sure, maybe the OP thought that would be the case.

Comment: Thank you very much for that Kryten!

`
const FormCell = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <a className="pdf-name" onClick={this.prop.functionName}>{data.item.extension.nameCodeDes}</a>


{
        order: 1,
        columnName: 'forms',
        displayName: 'Documents',
        columnComponent: {
          component: <FormCell functionName={Docs.downloadDocument} />,
          actions: [],
        },`

Comment: @FelixKling - yes, I was more-or-less trying to explain it from the OP's point of view... but it came out somewhat unclear. I'll revise it later when I have a bit more time.