# Are Javascript arrow-functions bound permanently at creation or not bound at all: the case of object and class methods

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

(I've been informed by Stack Overflow that this question is likely to be downvoted or marked as duplicate, but I'd ask you not to, as I've been poring through Stack Overflow answers to try to answer it and found posts that say conflicting things, which is what I'm trying to resolve).

I'm trying to understand the binding of arrow functions (as well as how that relates to their use as object and class methods).  My understanding is that an arrow function is bound at the moment of creation, taking `this` from the context in which it is defined. Some posts say that this is so.  Some posts say the opposite, maintaining that a arrow function is simply not bound, such as this post, [Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this) , where the most highly-voted answer says:

> Short answer: this points at the nearest bound this - in the code
>   provided this is found in the enclosing scope.
>
> Longer answer: Arrow functions <s>bind their this when they are
>   created</s> do not have this, arguments or other special names bound
>   at all - when the object is being created the name this is found in
>   the enclosing scope, not the person object.

I created a small [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBJKNg) example to test out which is correct, and I believe that indeed, arrow functions are bound permanently when created: if you assign an arrow function to a property of an object then call that function in the context of another object, it still maintains the `this` it had when it was created.

Which is it?  Are arrow functions bound permanently at creation to the `this` of the context in which they were created, or not bound at all?

If they are indeed bound when created, is that the reason you can use an arrow function as a method in an ES6 class?  That is to say in this case

```
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
    this.myVariable = 0;
    console.log("in constructor this is",this)
        this.myMethod = () => {
            console.log("in myMethod this is",this)

            this.myVariable++;
        };
    }
```

the arrow function myMethod is simply bound to the `this` which the constructor has defined as the context for the instance being created?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Arrow functions do not have a `this`. See, for example, [MDN's article on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Note that that page also mentions that they are not well-suited for member functions...

Answer (score 1):

Actually both say the same, while "`this` is found in the enclosing scope" is probably technically more correct. What matters here is that "the scope" is lexically determined, so it doesn't matter how and where you call the function, but rather were it was declared:

```
const a = () => this; // global scope

function b() {
  const c = () => this; // function scope of b
}
```

One could say that the scope is bound to a function when it gets declared, and as the scope also contains a context (`this`), the context (`this`) gets bound too.

Maybe the whole concept gets more clear if we imagine `this` is a regular variable:

```
const this = window;

const a = () => this; // global scope, "this" is window

function b(this) { // context determined on call
  const c = () => this; // scope of the b function
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But this would mean the "enclosing scope" _at the time the arrow function is created_, not when it is used?  That's what's confusing me.

Comment: @cerulean yes, scope is determined lexically.

Comment: Thus, continuing from your example, if one were to use the function `a` in the context of an object -- `const a = () => this; const obj = { fun: a }; console.log(obj.fun());`, the result would still be the global scope?

Comment: @cerulean yes, exactly.