# Error with referring to object with 'this' keyword with arrow function

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, ecmascript-5, arrow-functions

I created an object with object constructor ,made a prototype function.But when I called that function 'this' keyword not referring to object

```
function Person(name,age,location){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.location = location;
}

var person1 = new Person('john',22,'Pakistan');

Person.prototype.greet = ()=>{
  console.log(this.name + "says Hi");
};

person1.greet();
```

But when I used simple anonymous function ,the problem gets solved.

```
Person.prototype.greet = function(){
   console.log(this.name + "says Hi");
};
```

Why it's not working with arrow function?

Comment: there `this` is `window`.

Comment: Also potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this