# ViewChildren in dynamically rendered reactive form showing "undefined"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically render a form, and then cycle through each of the elements using @ViewChildren. However, the query appears not to be finding anything as I'm getting a zero length array back in `ngAfterViewInit` at the bottom of the following code. (For reference, here's the Stackblitz: https://angular-4lqtap.stackblitz.io). I've found several articles relating to this topic, but none have solved the issue I'm facing.

```
import { Directive, Component, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({selector: '[foo]'})
export class IdVar {
  // TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
  @Input() idString !: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
            <form #myForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="form">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let itm of testArr; let i = index"> 
              {{i}}: <input [foo] [id]="i" />
              <foo [idString]="i">{{i}}:&nbsp;</foo>
              </ng-container>
             </form>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {

  @Input() name: string;
  form: FormGroup;
  formControls={};
  testArr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  @ViewChildren('foo') id: QueryList<IdVar>; 


  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
    this.testArr.forEach((itm)=>{
      this.formControls[itm] = new FormControl(itm);
      this.form.addControl(itm, this.formControls[itm]);
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>console.log(this.id.length),1000);
  }

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any solutions or workarounds? Tks!

NEW ADDITION BELOW (got rid of earlier "undefined" error):

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried `#foo` in the template rather that just `foo`, inside the input?

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Making some progress . . . added NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA and CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to @NgModule.schemas in App-Module, and added AfterViewInit hook. With these changes, I eliminated the `this.id` undefined error, but unfortunately still have nothing happening in the `forEach` loop. So getting closer, but still have some work to do . . . Any ideas, please share! Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some changes that you need to do:

You need to add the directive in the `declarations` in the `app.module.ts`.

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent, IdVar } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, IdVar ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You are using a directive as a component, I think you dont need this line:

```
<foo [idString]="i">{{i}}:&nbsp;</foo>
```

The ViewChildren works with classes not with the selector,so you should change the line:

```
@ViewChildren('foo') id: QueryList<IdVar>;
```

to:

```
@ViewChildren(IdVar) id: QueryList<IdVar>;
```

Another note, you don't really need the extra []  in the directive

```
 <input foo [id]="i" />
```

I forked your example on stackblitz and modified it a little to make it work. 
I also changed the name of the directive to make it clear that it is a directive.

**Live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-viewchildren?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Piñeiro. Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: . . Regarding your point on "using a directive as a component", I played with the code and found that for: `selector: 'foo'` you can use "directive as component" (custom component), i.e. `<foo id="i". . . >`, but if: `selector: '[foo]'` (with square brackets), then the directive becomes an "attribute directive", as in `<input foo id="i" . . . >` . . . interestingly the two are mutually exclusive, so with square brackets the query only picks up the `<input>`'s and without square brackets only the `<foo>`'s . . .  Many thanks again for all the great help!!