# Using the this keyword to itterate through a jquery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

So I have a jQuery code which on a button click logs the values of every input field on my page:

I have tried this method with forEach method on inputs but it says it' not a function, why can't I use this method here?

```js
$("#submit").click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let inputs = $("input");

  inputs.each(() => {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

But the problem here is that the *this* keyword here refers to `#submit`, How could I achieve my goal here using only the this keyword , and why is this here referring to `#submit` and not the `input`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an arrow function. They don't re-bind `this`. 
Instead, the `this` of the enclosing lexical scope is used.

```
$("#submit").click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let inputs = $("input");

  inputs.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Should work just fine.

---

More information on arrow functions and the behaviour of `this`: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you for your response, so In this case the arrow function ignores it's local scope and the this keyword corresponds to the base function?

Comment: You can still use the arrow function. Receive the reference to the elemnt as an argument instead of using the scope

Comment: @Alex That is correct.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Of course you could do that. But I don't see a reason for using a lambda expression over a normal function expression here. I mean, not re-binding `this` is pretty much the main use-case of arrow functions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh ok , would it be possible for you to provide an example, I can't quite visualize what you mean ,thank you.

Comment: @Alex sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/zne10fp5/1/

Answer (score 0):

this is one possible solution;

```
// should always to assign vars first and then use them
var $this = $(this);
var $submit = $("#submit");
$submit.click(e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let inputs = $("input");

      inputs.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getInputs(){
  let inputs = $("input");

  inputs.forEach(() => {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
}
$("#submit").click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  getInputs()
});
```

This puts the inputs in a separate function, keeping the `this` variable from being overwritten.