# Service Layer Unit testing with Sinon.js - Error "x" is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs, sinon

I have followed the medium guide :
https://medium.com/@tehvicke/integration-and-unit-testing-with-jest-in-nodejs-and-mongoose-bd41c61c9fbc trying to develop a test suite. My code is exactly like his but I am having the **TypeError: Tournament is not a constructor**

I put some code, so you can see what I am trying to do.

**TournamentService.js**

```
const createTournament = (Tournament) => (tournamentObj) => {
  const {name, creator} = tournamentObj;
  const newTournament = new Tournament({name, creator});
  return newTournament.save();
};
```

**TournamentService.test.js**

```
const TournamentService = require("../TournamentService");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("create Tournament test", () => {
  it("creates a tournament", () => {
    const save = sinon.spy();
    console.log("save ", save);
    let name;
    let creator;

    const MockTournamentModel = (tournamentObject) => {
      name = tournamentObject.name;
      creator = tournamentObject.creator;
      return {
        ...tournamentObject,
        save,
      };
    };

    const tournamentService = TournamentService(MockTournamentModel);
    const fintoElemento = {
      name: "Test tournament",
      creator: "jest",
    };

    tournamentService.createTournament(fintoElemento);
    const expected = true;
    const actual = save.calledOnce;

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    expect(name).toEqual("Test tournament");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error, the problem was that I was trying to create the MockTournamentModel with an arrow function, instead you should use a classic function (or some package that re-compile into a classic function)

the keyword **new** does a few things:

- It creates a new object. The type of this object is simply object.

  **- It sets this new object's internal, inaccessible, [[prototype]] (i.e.
  __proto__) property to be the constructor function's external, accessible, prototype object (every function object automatically has
  a prototype property).**
- It makes the this variable point to the newly created object.
- It executes the constructor function, using the newly created object
  whenever this is mentioned.
- It returns the newly created object, unless the constructor function
  returns a non-null object reference. In this case, that object
  reference is returned instead.

**The arrow function *do not have* this, arguments or other special names bound at all.**

That's why it did not work with an arrow function.. hope this will help someone else avoid my mistake!

https://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

[Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)