# is there any chance to get the outer scope in Proxy?

Tags: javascript, proxy, scope, metaprogramming

I am Proxing an object in a custom class and I'd like to get access to the methods and properties of that same class within my Proxy Object. Is it possible?

I thought there is a way to bind the context but it didn't work for me neight with apply, call nor bind.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.state = new Proxy(this.initialState, {
      set(target, prop, value) {
        // some logic goes here              
      }
    })
  }

  methodIneedToReach() {}

}
```

I need it to structure the code and prevent the mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either store the value of `this` in a variable called `that` for example and use `that.methodIneedToReach` inside the `set` method, or, better yet, use an arrow function for `set`. Since [arrow functions don't have their own `this` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28798330/9867451), they will use the surrounding one which is, in this case, the instance of your class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.state = new Proxy(this.initialState, {
      set: (target, prop, value) => {                     // set is an arrow function
        this.methodIneedToReach();                        // works because 'this' inside here points to your class
      }
    })
  }

  methodIneedToReach() {}
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.initialState = { message: "Hello World!" };
  
    this.state = new Proxy(this.initialState, {
      set: (target, prop, value) => {
        this.methodIneedToReach();
      }
    })
  }

  methodIneedToReach(value) {
    console.log("'methodIneedToReach' is called");
  }
}

let inst = new MyClass();
inst.state.message = "Bye world!";
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I was a bit stuck on that. Code was messed up since I couldn’t arrange it into separate methods

Comment: @Valaryo you're welcome! I'm glad I could help. Happy coding!