# I'm not able to retrieve a variable from an object

Tags: javascript, object, electron

For some reason, I'm not able to get any value from this object:

```
function ContextMenu(id){
    this.ID = id;
}
ContextMenu.prototype.attachTo = (element, v = false) => {
    var menuID = this.ID;
    console.log(menuID);//undefined!
    [...]
};
```

Any idea why? This code is a part of the preload file in electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re defining `attachTo` as an arrow function, which means `this.ID` is pointing to the global scope. It’s giving you the value of `window.ID`, which is undefined.

Using `function(element, v=false){ /* the rest of your code goes here */` should solve your problem.

You can read more about it in this answer: [Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, you can solve this problem by doing this:

```
ContextMenu.prototype.attachTo = function(element, v = false){
    var menuID = this.ID;
    console.log(menuID);
    [...]
};
```