# Access object properties from methods on the object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as follows;

```
export const initialState = {

    name: '',
    acceptable: false,
    identified: false,
    variation: false,
    variationText: () => {
      return name.toUpperCase() //as an example
    }
    
}


//use it kind of like this, so that the item's properties are transposed, but any missing attributes
//or the methods are maintained.
return {...initialState, ...item}
```

When I attempt to access the attributes within the method, it isn't available.

Thanks you.

Comment: *"export cost initialState"* co**n**st?

Comment: I guess it would be possible to use `new class { /*...(but with ...=...;)*/ }()`, to have the arrow function's `this` bind to the object, but it feels like it would be bad style. More of a "look what i can do", than properly solving the issue?

Comment: spelling mistake, apologies. I'll update to const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript dosen't have any form of implicit `this` like some other languages do, to access a property on an object you have to explicitly refer to the object (unless you use the deprecated `with` statement).

In your example, you'd use the name of the constant:

```
export const initialState = {

    name: '',
    acceptable: false,
    identified: false,
    variation: false,
    variationText: () => {
      return initialState.name.toUpperCase()
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    
}
```

---

Side note: `variationText` is not a *method* in your code, it's an arrow function bound to a property. This is important because if it were a method, in addition to using `initialState` as shown above, you could probably (depending on how the method were called) use `this`. But you can't with an arrow function assigned to a property, because arrow functions *close over* `this`, they don't get them set by how the function is called. ([More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this).)

So if you made it a method, and **if** the method were called in the usual way, you could use `this`:

```
export const initialState = {

    name: '',
    acceptable: false,
    identified: false,
    variation: false,
    variationText() {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return this.name.toUpperCase()
//           ^^^^^
    }
    
}
```

But it's possible to call that method with the wrong `this`; [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).