# Can someone explain this code to me please?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I've read many posts about this 'e' and about arrow functions, but I don't get it.

```js
myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: e stands for event

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: You are passing e to the callback function as an argument for the mousedown event and reading its properties in the function

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3001761

Comment: Seems focussed enough to me, but not enough to argue about it with people.

Comment: We are missing a "Please look it up on MDN" close

Answer (score 2):

That code calls the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method on the `myDiv` object, which I assume is an HTML element. It passes in two arguments:

- `'mousedown'`, a string telling `addEventListener` what event to attach the event handler to, and
- `e => {/*...*/}`, the event handler function to attach

Later, if the `mousedown` event occurs for that element, the browser will call the event handler function with an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object as the only argument to the handler. The handler receives that argument in its `e` parameter and uses properties on that `Event` object (`clientX` and `clientY`), assigning them to the variables `x` and `y` and then outputting `x` to the browser console via [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

---

I should note that unless `x` and `y` are declared in code you haven't shown, that event handler falls prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by assigning to undeclared identifiers. If `x` and `y` are meant to only be used within the event handler function, they should be declared there with `const` or `let`:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  console.log(x);
});
```

(There's also no reason to assign to `y` unless it's being used for something.)

Comment: Also the `e => { ... }` corresponds to `function(e) { ... }`

Comment: Ok. Cool! I get it. thaks a lot.  I know about declaring variables and the fact that Y is there for no reason. I should'nt have put it this way. Thanks again for taking some time to answer.

Comment: @Posoroko - You're welcome, happy coding!

Comment: @mplungjan - *Mostly*. :-) There'd be a big difference if the handler used `this` of course, as they often do. (Posoroko - If you use an arrow function, `this` will be the same inside the function as outside it. With event handlers, you sometimes want `this` to be controlled by the code calling the function. The browser code calling an `addEventListener` callback will set `this` to the element you hooked the event on, for instance. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this).)

Comment: Yes, however in both cases we can use e.target

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes, or `e.currentTarget` for the same thing `this` refers to when the browser controls `this`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Callback function in event handler

```js
/*object*/.addEventListener(/*type*/, (e) => { /*code*/ });
```

The `e` parameter refers to the event that occurred, causing the listener to fire.
The callback takes the parameter that is automatically accessible.
2) What is clientX and clientY? These are the positions of the client when the user fired the event.