# javascript which type of function signature / style is better and we should use in real time?

Tags: javascript, function

So I am confused between all these four styles of declaring and defining a function ? all these work similarly but there must be a subtle difference between them :D

```js
var sayHello = function() {
  console.log("hello")
  console.log(arugments)//works
  console.log(this)//works
}

function sayhello() {
  console.log("hello")
  console.log(arugments)//works
  console.log(this)//work
}

var SayHello = function f() {
  console.log("hello")
    console.log(arugments)//works
  console.log(this)//work
}

var SayHellO = () =>{  
   console.log(arugments)//doesnt works
  console.log(this)//works
}
```

Comment: Some functional differences you will notice are _var function (or better const function) has to be declared before used_ and _arrow functions do not have a "this" when used as eventListeners_

Comment: Off-topic: get rid of the legacy `var` and use `let` and `const`

Comment: @Andreas what's the possible difference are those gonna make  ? let is good for block level scoping , a function at maximum exists in global context henceforth it can be accessed anywhere and const yeah it is reasonable to use but since it isn't gonna make it well documented since no one's gonna replace the function expression

Comment: @Andreas The root cause of using var seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186161/hoisting-does-not-seem-to-be-working-properly#comment124080384_70186161).

Comment: @mplungjan but an arrow function expression has this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this