# Svelte access the current element on event trigger

Tags: html, svelte

I am having issues with accessing an element values using `this` keyword.

this is what I have (doesn't work)

```html
{#if item}  
  <img src={'http://example.com/'+item.profile_img}
       on:error={this.src='/public/unknown.svg'}
       alt="user" />
{/if}
```

I would like to use `'/public/unknown.svg'` if the image doesn't exist and set the error to `null`.
I don't understand why the `this` keyword is `undefined` nor the normal `onerror` method doesn't work too.

This is the plain HTML version of what I want to achieve in svelte.

```html
<img src="http://example.com/non-existent-image.jpg"
     onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://example.com/existent-image.jpg';" />
```

I have tried it in various ways and failed, please help.

Answer (score 2):

use and inline function like this and get the target then set the src

```
{#if item}  
  <img src={'http://example.com/'+item.profile_img}
       on:error={(e) => {
           e.target.src='/public/unknown.svg'
       }}
       alt="user" />
{/if}
```

or if you prefer to use this you need to use `function` in order to access the correct this to the current tag

```
{#if item}  
  <img src={'http://example.com/'+item.profile_img}
       on:error={function() {
           this.src='/public/unknown.svg'
       }}
       alt="user" />
{/if}
```

Read more about [arrow functions and this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798362/5609501)